# Internet always on when VoLTE enabled in Redmi 3s Prime

Tags: data-connection, 4g

[image]
I m using Redmi 3s prime with jio 4G. Whenever VoLTE is enabled, my device internet is always active, regardless of whether mobile data is on or off. I can browse the Internet and watch online video even when mobile data is off. How can I turn off internet when VoLTE is enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Voice over LTE (VoLTE) uses mobile data (LTE). You can't turn off mobile data and use VoLTE. You can turn off mobile data and use a different voice connection like 3G.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it like this:

Go to `Settings` => `Mobile networks`. There, select `SIM 1(JIO)` and go to `Access Point Name (APN)` and click on `Restore to default`.

It is caused by changing APN Settings. I tried this fix on two R3S Prime devices and it worked on both of them.

Comment: But restoring default access point makes the phone lose VoLTE after a reboot or switch off.

Answer (score 0):

Voice over LTE (VoLTE) does not use mobile data. This feature is specifically for voice calling over a 4G (LTE) network, as the name suggests & it enables the user to make voice calls over a 4G network without the use of data. For more explanation, see the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpgFPR9mvpk